# Jinja, Flask and WTForms: how to pass parameters in field?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I am following this tutorial http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/

Here’s an example _formhelpers.html template with a macro:

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Here the register.html template which takes advantage of the _formhelpers.html template:

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post action="/register">
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.username) }}
    {{ render_field(form.email) }}
    {{ render_field(form.password) }}
    {{ render_field(form.confirm) }}
    {{ render_field(form.accept_tos) }}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Register>
</form>
```

It ends up generating a sequence of those:

```
<dt><label for="email">Email Address</label>
<dd><input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
```

I want to put more parameters and in a bit different fashion like:

```
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"
        placeholder="Email Address" value="{{ form.email }}"
        required>
```

How do I modify

```
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
```

to achieve that?

Comment: How does your title relate to the question?

Comment: Well spotted, fixed it.

Comment: [field documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__)

you can do `form.email(style="style")` im not sure if it will pass down html attributes. I remember having this problem too. But have since changed the code

Answer (score 4):

Coming from the [documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/fields.html#wtforms.fields.Field.__call__) you can do:

```
{{ form.email(class_="input-xlarge", 
              placeholder="Email Address",
              value="testemail@testing.com") }}
```

Which will render:

```html
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input-xlarge"
        placeholder="Email Address" value="testemail@testing.com"
        required>
```

Just replace "testemail@testing.com" with form.email without braces as you are already inside them.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work:
 File "/app/templates/register.html", line 53, in block "content"
    {{ render_field(form.email(class_="input-xlarge", placeholder="Email Address", value="testemail@testing.com")) }}
  File "/app/templates/_formhelpers.html", line 3, in template
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
AttributeError: 'HTMLString' object has no attribute '__ call __'

Comment: You cant pass it to render_field. You need to modify the code so that the render_field only renders the errors. Unless you are only updating information that can be made generic like class.

Then you can modify the render_field to have `<dd>{{ field(class_="class you want", **kwargs)|safe }}`

Comment: I think I see what you mean. But how can I add a class to __some__ of fields in _formhelpers.html, not for __all__ of them in _formhelpers.html ?

Comment: Have a class parameter for render_field `{% macro render_field(field, class_to_use) %}` and then you can use `{{ field(class_=class_to_use, **kwargs)|safe }}`

Comment: How would you pass the required tag in? It's just there, to I suppose you used `InputRequired()`. But how do you pass it in jinja2?