# Jinja2 how to put variable inside jinja block?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Hello I have an html file with code similar to this:

```
<div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-key-25"></i></span>
                </div>
                {{ form.abc1(placeholder="abc 1",class="form-control",type="password")}}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-time-alarm"></i></span>
                </div>
                {{ form.abc2(placeholder="abc 2",class="form-control") }}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-time-alarm"></i></span>
                </div>
                {{ form.abc3(placeholder="abc 3",class="form-control") }}
              </div>
            </div>
```

How could I make it so with a jinja for loop I can do something like the following python's solution:

```
i = 1
while i < 3:
  exec(f"abc{i} = {i}")
  i += 1
```

basically I need to make abcs in the html code using a jinja loop

```
{% for element in abclist %}
```

and here be able to define the following:

```
{{ form.abc%element here%(placeholder="abc %element here%",class="form-control") }}
```

Comment: instead of `exec(f"abc{i} = {i}")` you can pass a list to jinja template while rensering, `exec(f"abc{i} = {i}")` seems a strange and overkill and not a good use for me.

Comment: my problem is getting how to put a variable inside this block; {{ form.abc3(placeholder="abc 3",class="form-control") }}

Comment: the biggest mistake is using `exec(f"abc{i} = {i}")` to create unique variables. You should use standard list for this `abc = []`, `abc.append(i)` - and then you can use `for`-loop in Python and in Jinja to work with this. And all values (like `placeholder`) you should set in Python before you send it to Jinja

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot have nested double brackets in Jinja like this {{ {{}} }}
The best (and cleaner) solution would be to use macros. Shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768370/jinja-flask-and-wtforms-how-to-pass-parameters-in-field)

Then you can use your loop:

```
{% for element in form %}
{{ render_field(element) }}
```